# Coordinating config and example files across conda environment

Tags: python, configuration, virtual-environment

Let's say I have an data.csv and a config.yaml file for my package and they have been part of pkg_resources. That package is loaded in several possible conda environments used by our group concurrently. Some may also access the package using a pip dev install. The motive for this is managing dependencies -- seldom will anyone want to change configurations.

How do folks usually handle this? I can guess that I might make a directory ~/.mypack if the directory doesn't exist at import time and just dump to there from whatever environment is activated. Is there a better python-supported way?